# Splitting DataTable c# and Print result to PDF File

Tags: c#, datatable, itext

I am in a tough situation..Please help me..
 I want to print data from datatable to pdf ,that portion is working fine..but the problem is that in some cases the datatable row values(single row but column value is long) becomes too long so in that cases  i want to split that exeeded data to the next pdf page..  in other situations i have handled using rowcount.. that is if rowcount value is 2 then first row data is written to the first pdfpage and so on but in this situation only single row but each column value is too long ...here how i split the exceed data to next page??
I am using itextsharp for generating pdf reports...

Comment: May be like you are using rowcount the same way you can apply word or character count for this case.

Comment: can u plz provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

To split long rows across different pages, set the PdfPTable.SplitLate property to false:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.SplitLate = false;
```

For more details refer to this example: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#189-headerfooter2.java